# How to add an exe path to the windows registry, to get executed on the native mode?

Tags: windows, registry, native

I have to run an exe file in the native mode so i guess adding it to the registry is the only option i am having.Please give some input how this can be done?

Comment: The "Startup" folder is still there, and it's what you should be using. Place a shortcut to your executable in that folder for the user (or all users) you want.

Comment: @CodyGray: so far as I know, the startup folder only runs Win32 code, not native code.  (That's native as in "calling the Windows kernel directly" not native as in "not .NET".)

Comment: @Harry Yes, I'm sure that's true. I assumed by "native" he meant "desktop" as opposed to "the new Windows 8 stuff". I could be wrong, but there aren't many people writing apps that call the kernel functions directly...

Comment: @CodyGray: indeed, the question was ambiguous - it's unfortunate IMO that the .NET folks overloaded the meaning of "native".  I've never heard anyone call desktop apps (as opposed to Metro) "native" before but I suppose it was inevitable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of the [`BootExecute`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102985) value, located in this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
```

This is a `REG_MULTI_SZ` value, i.e., it contains multiple strings.  Each string contains an arbitrary identifier, the name of the executable to run, and the arguments to pass to the executable.  For example, the default setting contains only one string:

```
autocheck autochk *
```

Here `autocheck` is an arbitrary label, `autochk` indicates that the executable to run is `c:\windows\system32\autochk.exe`, and `*` is the argument string passed to `autochk.exe`.